# Python Seleniume Multiple Buttons with same name

Tags: python, selenium

For the below HTML code, I want to select the button in the DIV for 2022 November

```
<div class="reportTitleNonMobile ng-binding">
                                        2022 November
                                
                                        <button class="myButton" ng-show="!gridFile.monthOpen" ng-click="toggleMonthReport(gridFile)">Open</button>
                                        
                                        <button class="myButton ng-hide" ng-show="gridFile.monthOpen" ng-click="toggleMonthReport(gridFile)">Close</button>
                                
                                    </div>
```

However the same is repeated for all the months.
Below is the link to the larger HTML Code for reference. Any help is appreciated:

https://workdrive.zohoexternal.com/external/ecd06139063100a07635e16e74cb43a21504e8cb0b2c3bd57d6f3d7e317724d5

I have tried the following:
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportHeaderCol4NonMobile"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/fieldset/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6jiJ.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6jiJ.png)/div').click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Open')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6jiJ.png).click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name('button.myButton')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6jiJ.png).click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name('myButton')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6jiJ.png).click()

and a bunch more but none of them seem to work and I end up with error Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

---- Edit / Addition---

I even tried the suggestion from @AbiSaran with Xpath as (.//*[@class='reportTitleAreaNonMobile'])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6jiJ.png)//button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6jiJ.png) but got the same error.

I feel the Xpath's are correct since I am able to find them in Chrome > Inspect screen. But my python code fails.
[image: Image of Chrome > Inspect]

-----------Solution---
The solution below was pointing to accurate Xpath but was not working since the website was opening a new tab and the code continued to look for the element in the previous tab. I has the switch the active tab using the doe below and it worked fine.

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below XPath:

For the 'Open' button in '2022 November':

```
(.//*[@class='reportTitleAreaNonMobile'])[1]//button[1]
```

For the 'Close' button in '2022 November':

```
(.//*[@class='reportTitleAreaNonMobile'])[1]//button[2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but it didn't work.. got the same errors
... 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[@class='reportTitleAreaNonMobile'])[1]//button[1]").click()
...
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(.//*[@class='reportTitleAreaNonMobile'])[1]//button[1]"}

Comment: From the html source you've posted, it is working. If its not working, post the URL, it will be helpful to debug.

Comment: Thank you @AbiSaran , You providing the correct Xpath helped me explore other options to fix the issue.